# can a network interface join multiple groups

Tags: networking, ip, multicast

when i talk about ip multicasting, we know it is possible that:

1. one or more processes can join the same group on the same interface
2. one or more interfaces can join the same group

my question is that is it possible for **one** interface to join **multiple** groups so that it can send or receive different groups multicast

Comment: I don't agree that the question is off-topic. It concerns multicasting, which is implemented via programming at both ends, and it raises a valid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. IP multicasting is at a higher-level than NICs. The NIC just knows about ethernet multicast, and doesn't care about IP or IGMP.

NICs usually support multicast filters, you can add up to a certain number of multicast ethernet addresses that the NIC should listen for. Once you surpass that limit, the only way to listen to more multicast addresses is to put the NIC in promiscuous mode, with the performance degradation that may entail on a busy network.

Comment: thanks , i am totally new the multicast thing,just know a few concept and dont have any practical experience.How can i design an experiment ?

Comment: @Tracy for Windows start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms739172(v=vs.85).aspx